# how to add the column values to the next row of the same column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

how to add the column values to the next row of the same column in pandas

how to update how to add/update the column values to the next row of the same column in pandas image attached for your refence(here i want to update till the next value available)

Comment: image attached for your refence?

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':['A','B','C'], 'Col_2':[1,2,3]})
df
###
  Col_1  Col_2
0     A      1
1     B      2
2     C      3
```

If you wanna insert values to **specific index location**,

```
new_row = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':'D', 'Col_2':4}, index=[1])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:1], new_row, df.iloc[1:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
df
###
  Col_1  Col_2
0     A      1
1     D      4 ⬅
2     B      2
3     C      3
```

If you wanna **append values** to the last/bottom,

```
bot_row = ['E', 5]
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([bot_row], columns=df.columns)]).reset_index(drop=True)
df
###
  Col_1  Col_2
0     A      1
1     D      4
2     B      2
3     C      3
4     E      5 ⬅
```

If you wanna **update** specific row,

```
df.loc[3] = ['F',6]
df
###
  Col_1  Col_2
0     A      1
1     D      4
2     B      2
3     F      6 ⬅
4     E      5
```

If you wanna update a specific **cell**,

```
df.loc[2, 'Col_1'] = 'G'
df
###
  Col_1  Col_2
0     A      1
1     D      4
2   → G ←    2
3     F      6
4     E      5
```